# How to reference the selected row in UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am getting the "unexpectedly found nil fatal error" here. basically I have a picker view where the options you can choose from reference keys in a dictionary. I want to reference these keys to update a label with a (random) value within the key

here is a sample of what I mean

```
func updateValue {
    desiredValue = myDictionary[pickedKey]
}
```

the "pickedKey" is what is currently picked on the picker view, and that references a key in a dictionary. it's the pickedKey I'm having a problem with. If I hardcode a random key in there it works just fine but obviously I want the key that the user picks within PIckerView.

does anyone know why i'm getting the nil fatal error? it also won't let me declare pickedKey as optional, it says "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : String]' with an index of type 'String?'"

update: here is the code for the pickerView

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


        //the selected pick will be stored in pickedKey
        pickedKey = pickerArray[row]

        //the desired value will be the value from the picked key in myDictionary
        desiredValue = myDictionary[pickedKey]!

        foodLabel.text = desiredValue

    }
```

keep in mind that pickerArray is an Array of they keys in myDictionary

```
var pickerArray: Array = Array(myDictionary.keys.sorted())
```

Comment: Could you provide more code samples on how you are getting the pickedKey from the pickerView.

Comment: Based on your error, you are trying to use a dictionary as the key rather than a string. Like you said if you do it manually it works. If you provide the code for how you are getting the data from the pickerview then should be able to resolve this quickly.

Comment: i updated the code; basically I want "pickedKey" to work in other functions and for it to know that pickedArray[row] is selected in the PickerView

Comment: I know what's wrong - will post answer to help you

Comment: i don't think I did a good job of explaining my problem  - BUT luckily I just figured it out. I should have added this line of code to the updateValue() function:         pickerView(myPickerOutlet, didSelectRow: rowIndex, inComponent: 1)  it was the "rowIndex" that was throwing me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary key is a `string`:

**Update your key sort**

```swift
var pickerArray: [String] = myDictionary.keys.sorted()
```

---

Replace your didSelectRow with this.

```swift
var pickedKey: String?

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if 
       let pickedKey = pickerArray[row] as? String,
       let desiredValue = myDictionary[pickedKey] {
           foodLabel.text = desiredValue     
    } else {
        // TODO: Error
    }
}
```

Ensure you do try not you use force casting as crashes will happen if you have issues.